# Strange redirect to edit.php after /wp-admin/admin.php include in my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a plugin, and I am experiencing a strange problem.

In one of my plugin files, I need to include the `wp-admin/admin.php` to get the `$menu` and `$submenu` variables.

However, if no headers are sent, before requireing the `admin.php` file, I am redirected to: `edit.php?post_type=page`.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
// Get root dir
    $root = explode('wp-content', dirname( __FILE__ ));
    $root = $root[0];

// Require

echo 'test'; // if this echo is here (headers sent), it will not redirect
    require_once($root . 'wp-admin/admin.php');
```

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way, to include the wordpress root, than what I have done above?

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

By the way; the exact same plugin works fine on two other wordpress installations.

### Update!

I have found out that something is redirecting away from the plugin-file using `wp_redirect`. I have made a backtrace on wp_redirect, which you can access here: http://justpaste.it/dkqw

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are not redirecting. You are including a file in your script.

Comment: Exactly. Please carefully reread my question, and let me know, if there is still anything you misunderstand.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include this file in the first place. Can you provide more context where all this is happening?

Comment: why are you including the wp-admin.php file? ... why not use the WordPress Walker Class to access the menu and submenu - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker -